# How to Reset City value when Country Changes

Tags: angularjs

Here im using Angularjs cascading dropdownList as `Country,State,City` when i select as Country-->India,State-->Telangana,City--->Hydrabad.But when i change Country as India to another City is not Reset until i wont change State

```
<b>Country</b>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="Cnt_Id" ng-required="true" ng-options="I.Cnt_Id as I.Cnt_Name for I in countryData" ng-change="GetState()">

</select>
<b>State</b>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="Sts_Id" ng-required="true" ng-options="I.Sts_Id as I.Sts_Name for I in StateData" ng-change="GetCity()">
    <option value="">{{StateVal}}</option>

</select>
<b>City</b>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="City_Id" ng-required="true" ng-options="I.City_Id as I.City_Name for I in CityData">
    <option>Select City</option>
    <option value="">{{CityVal}}</option>
</select>
```

**Angular.js**

```
function GetCountry() {
    var CountrySer = Myservice.GetCountryData();
    CountrySer.then(function(d) {
        $scope.countryData = d.data;
        $scope.StateVal = "Please Select Staes";
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log('Error....')
    })
}

$scope.GetState = function() {
    var StateSer = Myservice.GetstaeService($scope.Cnt_Id)
    StateSer.then(function(d) {
        $scope.StateData = d.data;
        $scope.CityVal = "Please Select City";

    })
}
$scope.GetCity = function() {
    var Cityser = Myservice.Getcity($scope.Sts_Id);
    Cityser.then(function(d) {
        $scope.CityData = d.data;
    })
}
```

Comment: please post json data or even better try to reproduce your issue in fiddle or plunkr

Comment: @maxim Country,State,Citys Are working fine but after selecting 3 fildes if i cange country name state names get Reset but city names are not Reset here i need to reset city dropdown whem country name change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset State and City on the selection of Country
Reset City on the selection of State
That's it

```
function GetCountry() {
    var CountrySer = Myservice.GetCountryData();
    CountrySer.then(function(d) {
        $scope.countryData = d.data;
        $scope.StateVal = "Please Select Staes";
        $scope.StateData = []; //new line
        $scope.CityVal = "Please Select City"; //new line
        $scope.CityData = []; //new line
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log('Error....')
    })
}

$scope.GetState = function() {
    var StateSer = Myservice.GetstaeService($scope.Cnt_Id)
    StateSer.then(function(d) {
        $scope.StateData = d.data;
        $scope.CityVal = "Please Select City";
        $scope.CityData = []; //new line
    })
}
$scope.GetCity = function() {
    var Cityser = Myservice.Getcity($scope.Sts_Id);
    Cityser.then(function(d) {
        $scope.CityData = d.data;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear out cities list when new state values are fetched

```
$scope.GetState = function () {
        var StateSer = Myservice.GetstaeService($scope.Cnt_Id)
        StateSer.then(function (d) {
            $scope.StateData = d.data;
            $scope.CityData= [];
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank u soo much mR @Shazad Bhai

Comment: may i know ur email

Comment: @Hussain Welcome. shahzad.adil00@gmail.com